# Set a text field to 2 values

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to set a text field to 2 different values

```
value1 *new line*
value 2
```

This is my current solution

```
set(handles.text1,'String',a);
set(handles.text1,'String',Fs);
```

It the textfield as Fs, completely ignoring `a`. How can I get it to post both values? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to format a text field to have 2 values as you have described. `set(handles.text1,'String',sprintf('%-s\n%-s',a,Fs))`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `%-s` do compared to `%s`?